# Read data from mysqli_fetch_array like a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysqli

When I use `mysqli_fetch_array()` I get an array, but how do I read the values? Is a While-Loop the only option, or can I pick any value from a row and column like a multidimensional array with index like `row[0] column [3]` ?

Comment: it's an array. you read data from it like any other array...`var_dump($arr)` to see what you got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while` loop fetches you a row per iteration.

You can get all rows as multidimensional array with [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

After that you can use pick your values with `[rowNum][colNum]`

But beware when your result has lot of rows - array can be very big and cause memory or other issues.

**Update to clarify:**

if you want to receive multidimensional array of rows there are **two** ways:

**First:** iterate over mysqli_result with `fetch_assoc`/`fetch_array` and append row to array:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo $rows[0]['whatever'];
```

**Second:** receive all results with one function call:

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $rows[0]['whatever'];
```

That's all. No more methods are available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I should do something like this? while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $persons[] = $row;
}

Comment: Yes you can. In the end you will have the same array as with `mysqli_fetch_all`

Comment: OK, but are there any better ways to do it? Do I need to use the While loop to add the result to an array?

Comment: Better ways to do what?

Comment: To read the result flike an array. But I guess with the $persons[2]['id']; I get the id of the third row?

Comment: @3D-kreativ If you want to get all results at once then use `mysqli_fetch_all` but as @u_mulder mentioned, it causes memory issues when data is so large. So other ways around it would be to paginate your data by `limit` if you're display results to the user. Or use while loop to filter the result or use it straight ahead.

Comment: You can simply var_dump your result variable to the screen and then simply just traverse your result down to what you need. like if you want your Result's 3rd item's name column then you can access it like so $row[2]['name']

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you are returning your results from the database.

there are flags in your mysqli_fetch_array function which you can set to modify your returned result.

If you use `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` or in OOP `$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

then you can access your returned result as column name in your while loop like $row['name'] or $row['age']

Or if you use `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);` or in OOP `$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);`

then you can access your returned result in while loop like $row[0] or $row[3]

Simple example would be

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['age'];
}
```

For further information. Read [PHP.net Fetch Array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that your goal is just to get a single value. If that is the case, you should limit your query to only return what you're looking for rather than getting everything and then finding what you want in the results with PHP.

For the column, specify the one column you want instead of using `*`, (`SELECT one_column FROM your_table)` and for the row, either use a `WHERE` clause to select a specific id (provided that is defined on your table) or use a `LIMIT` clause to select a specific row number from the result set. Then you won't have to fetch in a loop or fetch all. Your query result (if it's successful) will just have one row with one column, and you can fetch once and get your value.

Granted, if you're going to need to do this repeatedly (i.e. in a loop), it isn't the best approach.

Comment: I want to use an array so that I can divide the result into smaller groups. Instead of a query for each group and use between x and x because I also want to get a random result.